# UIBarButtonItem strange error

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uibarbuttonitem

I have a strange error, i created an UIBarButtonItem programatically, it works fine on simulator and on device when its connected to Xcode. But whenever i unplug the device, the app crashes when i touch the button.

Here is how i create the button, and assign it to the navigation bar:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(backToMainPage:)];
```

Method:

```
- (void)backToMainPage:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"...");
}
```

---

This is the error i got:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x40290020
Crashed Thread:  0
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3693d386 _ZL12realizeClassP7class_t + 34
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3693d3e6 _ZL12realizeClassP7class_t + 130
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36937836 prepareForMethodLookup + 74
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36937740 lookUpMethod + 40
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3693770c _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 12
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36936fc4 objc_msgSend_uncached + 20
6   UIKit                           0x30f28fa8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
7   UIKit                           0x30f28f64 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
8   UIKit                           0x30f28f42 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
9   UIKit                           0x30f28cb2 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 486
10  UIKit                           0x30f295ea -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 470
11  UIKit                           0x30f27acc -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 312
12  UIKit                           0x30f274ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 374
13  UIKit                           0x30f0d836 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350
14  UIKit                           0x30f0d0dc _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
15  GraphicsServices                0x33f30224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3494251c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
17  CoreFoundation                  0x349424be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3494130c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
19  CoreFoundation                  0x348c449e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
20  CoreFoundation                  0x348c4366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
21  GraphicsServices                0x33f2f432 GSEventRunModal + 130
22  UIKit                           0x30f3be76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
```

Can anyone help me what i did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you released your button....?

Comment: did you declare backToMainPage() in your header file ?

Comment: No, release is deprecated in >iOS 5.0. Yes, i declared in the header file.

Comment: Is it possible, that the garbage collector released the button? I tried the following, but that not worked: declared a variable in the header file (UIBarButtonItem *item), and then item = ... and self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item.

Comment: I would imagine that the viewcontroller gets released. Could you show where this viewcotroller is created and how its view gets on screen.

Comment: There is no garbage collection. The difference might be that in a debug setting objects get retained indefinitely for better logging.

Comment: @FelixLam Your suggestion was correct, the problem was in the creation. Thanks for your help! Btw. here is the code how i created the viewcontroller: [link]http://noob.hu/2012/04/10/screenshot.png

Comment: I added my comment as an answer: if you like you can mark it as answered ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that the viewcontroller gets released. Could you show where this viewcotroller is created and how its view gets on screen.

There is no garbage collection. The difference might be that in a debug setting objects get retained indefinitely for better logging

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:infoButton.currentImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showInfo:)] autorelease];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: if still not working clean your product or restart your mac and check it out if working.